# IdentityServer4 need to configure key material but cert is present

Tags: c#, .net, iis, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

When I publish my IdentityServer4 solution on my IIS server the log says "System.Exception: need to configure key material". This is strange because on my local machine it works fine.

I tried to console log the Issuer of the certificate and on my machine it works. The certificate is generated using 'KeyStore Explorer".

In the appsettings.json I put the path to the cert and the password. I updated the path param after the deployment on the server so it should point to it correctly.

This is my startup.cs:

```
namespace IdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }
        public static IConfiguration StaticConfig { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Environment = environment;
            StaticConfig = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // uncomment, if you want to add an MVC-based UI
            //services.AddControllersWithViews();

            //core 2.2
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("CertFilePath"));

            if (!File.Exists(fileName))

            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Signing Certificate is missing!");
            }
//This is where I import the cert
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, StaticConfig.GetValue<string>("CertPassword"));

//This is where I log the issuer
            Console.WriteLine("Issuer: " + cert.IssuerName);
            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddSigningCredential(cert); //This is where I add the cert

            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
            }
            else
            {
//Here the Exception my server throw
                throw new Exception("need to configure key material");
            }

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // uncomment if you want to support static files
            //app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            // uncomment, if you want to add an MVC-based UI
            //app.UseEndpoint(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            //});

            //core 2.2
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the Environment because in local I was using Development and on server Production